# Pandas - Pivot Multiple Categorical Columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe as such:

```
name = ['fred','fred','fred','james','james','rick','rick','jeff']
actionfigures = ['superman','batman','flash','greenlantern','flash','batman','joker','superman']
cars = ['lamborghini', 'ferrari','bugatti','ferrari','corvette','bugatti','bmw','bmw']
pets = ['cat','dog','bird','cat','dog','dog','fish','marmet']

test = pd.DataFrame({'name':name,'actfig':actionfigures,'car':cars,'pet':pets})

    actfig       car                name    pet
0   superman     lamborghini        fred    cat
1   batman       ferrari            fred    dog
2   flash        bugatti            fred    bird
3   greenlantern ferrari            james   cat
4   flash        corvette           james   dog
5   batman       bugatti            rick    dog
6   joker        bmw                rick    fish
7   superman     bmw                jeff    marmet
```

Forgive me if my terminology is incorrect, but I want to pivot the data so that I get counts for each value in the ['actionfigures','car','pet'] columns for each name.

```
    batman  flash   greenlantern    joker   superman    bmw bugatti corvette    ferrari lamborghini bird    cat dog fish    marmet
name                                                            
fred    1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
james   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
jeff    0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
rick    1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
```

I would have thought that `test.pivot_table(index='name',columns=['actfig','car','pet'],aggfunc='size'])` would do it, but it gives me some weird multi-level columns.

Thinking maybe I could concat `get_dummies` for each column then groupby name and sum, but feel like pandas prob has a better way.

How would this be done?

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`melt` and `pivot`

```
test.melt('name').assign(new=1).pivot('name','value','new').fillna(0)
Out[239]: 
value  batman  bird  bmw  bugatti  cat  corvette  dog  ferrari  fish  flash  \
name                                                                          
fred      1.0   1.0  0.0      1.0  1.0       0.0  1.0      1.0   0.0    1.0   
james     0.0   0.0  0.0      0.0  1.0       1.0  1.0      1.0   0.0    1.0   
jeff      0.0   0.0  1.0      0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0      0.0   0.0    0.0   
rick      1.0   0.0  1.0      1.0  0.0       0.0  1.0      0.0   1.0    0.0   
value  greenlantern  joker  lamborghini  marmet  superman  
name                                                       
fred            0.0    0.0          1.0     0.0       1.0  
james           1.0    0.0          0.0     0.0       0.0  
jeff            0.0    0.0          0.0     1.0       1.0  
rick            0.0    1.0          0.0     0.0       0.0
```

Or `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(test.set_index('name')).sum(level=0)
Out[248]: 
       actfig_batman  actfig_flash  actfig_greenlantern  actfig_joker  \
name                                                                    
fred               1             1                    0             0   
james              0             1                    1             0   
jeff               0             0                    0             0   
rick               1             0                    0             1   
       actfig_superman  car_bmw  car_bugatti  car_corvette  car_ferrari  \
name                                                                      
fred                 1        0            1             0            1   
james                0        0            0             1            1   
jeff                 1        1            0             0            0   
rick                 0        1            1             0            0   
       car_lamborghini  pet_bird  pet_cat  pet_dog  pet_fish  pet_marmet  
name                                                                      
fred                 1         1        1        1         0           0  
james                0         0        1        1         0           0  
jeff                 0         0        0        0         0           1  
rick                 0         0        0        1         1           0
```

Edit: As per PiR

```
pd.get_dummies(test.set_index('name'), prefix_sep='|').sum(level=0).rename(columns=lambda c: c.rsplit('|', 1)[1])
```

Comment: For your second approach, you can rename in line `pd.get_dummies(test.set_index('name'), prefix_sep='|').sum(level=0).rename(columns=lambda c: c.rsplit('|', 1)[1])`

Comment: Great answers, plus 1 to both of you

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
`pd.get_dummies` by parts

```
a = pd.get_dummies(test.actfig)
c = pd.get_dummies(test.car)
p = pd.get_dummies(test.pet)
n = pd.get_dummies(test.name).T

pd.concat([n.dot(d) for d in [a, c, p]], axis=1)

       batman  flash  greenlantern  joker  superman  bmw  bugatti  corvette  ferrari  lamborghini  bird  cat  dog  fish  marmet
fred        1      1             0      0         1    0        1         0        1            1     1    1    1     0       0
james       0      1             1      0         0    0        0         1        1            0     0    1    1     0       0
jeff        0      0             0      0         1    1        0         0        0            0     0    0    0     0       1
rick        1      0             0      1         0    1        1         0        0            0     0    0    1     1       0
```

---

**Option 2**
`stack` + `pd.crosstab`

```
test.set_index('name').stack().pipe(
    lambda x: pd.crosstab(x.index.get_level_values(0), x.values))

col_0  batman  bird  bmw  bugatti  cat  corvette  dog  ferrari  fish  flash  greenlantern  joker  lamborghini  marmet  superman
row_0                                                                                                                          
fred        1     1    0        1    1         0    1        1     0      1             0      0            1       0         1
james       0     0    0        0    1         1    1        1     0      1             1      0            0       0         0
jeff        0     0    1        0    0         0    0        0     0      0             0      0            0       1         1
rick        1     0    1        1    0         0    1        0     1      0             0      1            0       0         0
```

Comment: `pipe` is shock me ... I only do that when I training the model ~ :-), never thought it can be used in here ~

Comment: haven't used pipe before - what gets fed into it? aka what is x in the lambda function?

Comment: `x` is the return from `test.set_index('name').stack()`

Comment: so then the pipe is just to make it a 1-liner? as in if i just assigned `x=test.set_index('name').stack()` and then did `pd.crosstab(x.index.get_level_values(0), x.values)` i seem to get the same values